# How to pass variable to SQL script?

Tags: heroku-postgres

I want to pass a variable to SQL script run by `heroku pg:psql`.

Running a script without a variable can be achieved by:

`heroku pg:psql <script.sql`

To pass a variable to `psql`, I would do `psql -v assignment` but option `-v` doesn't work with `heroku pg:psql`.

I have tried also

`heroku pg:psql <(cat <(echo "\set username self") script.sql)`

but got an error:

Unknown database: /dev/fd/63. Valid options are: DATABASE_URL

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Got a response from official Heroku support.
Apparently, this cannot be done with `heroku pg:psql`.
Instead, `psql` can read DATABASE_URL environment variable in it's native form.
So, this should work:

```
psql -v username=self `heroku config | grep DATABASE_URL | sed -E 's/\S+\s+//'` < script.sql
```